# How to DRY the handling of Twitter API rate limit

Tags: python, twitter, exception, dry

I have the following code pattern to handle various exceptions that arise while accessing Twitter API. The basic pattern is:

```
while True:
    try:
        # 'access twitter api'
    except tweepy.error.TweepError:
        # 'handling the error'
```

I have multiple methods, e.g. `get_tweets()`, `get_friends()`, all of which use the same error handling pattern. How to DRY this?

For example, below is my `get_tweets()` method. How to re-use the error handling in this method in others?

```
def get_tweets(self, screen_name):        
    while True:
        try:
            rs = self.api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name)

        except tweepy.error.TweepError, e:
            if e.response.status_code == 404:
                print "%s does not exist" % (twitter_id)
                return None

            elif e.response.status_code == 429:
                print "out of quota"
                time.sleep(60 * 15)
                continue

            elif e.response.status_code == 503:
                print "Twitter down"
                time.sleep(60 * 15)
                continue

            else:
                print "%s, %s" % (twitter_id, e)
                continue
```

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of the except statement is repeated multiple places it might a good candidate for some reuse.

I see multiple ways you might do this, here are some options.

1. Define an error handler that can be used by multiple methods:

```
def get_tweets(self, screen_name):
    while True:
        try:
            rs = self.api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name)
        except tweepy.error.TweepError, e:
            error_handler(e)

def error_handler(self, e):
    # handle the error
```

Of course with this option we end up repeating

```
while True:
    try:
        # access twitter api
    except:
        # handle error
```

2. Instead you can create a general twitter call function which accepts a method and some arguments for the method.

```
def twitter_request(self, twitter_method, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        try:
            twitter_method(*args, **kwargs)
        except tweepy.error.TweepError, e:
            # handle the error

def get_tweets(self, screen_name):
    twitter_request(self.api.user_timeline, screen_name=screen_name)
```

These options can also be combined if you need the ability to replace the error handling function for some api calls by adding the error handler function as argument to `twitter_request`